# Property delegate not found on Firebase IOS example

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

i'm trying to add Firebase to my IOS application using their api Guide,
and i'm adding the "Register for remote notifications" code under my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in my `AppDelegate.m` as suggested by Firebase.
but it writes an error saying

```
Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'id'
```

here is my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

  //Register app for remote notifications
  if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
    UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
    (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
    [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
  } else {
    // iOS 10 or later
    #if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
    // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
    [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
    UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
    UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
    | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
    | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    }];
#endif
  }

  [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you added `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` to your AppDelegate.m `@interface` ?

Answer (score 0):

I executed your code in iOS 11 & iOS 8 , working for me. I think it is crashing somewhere else.